# how to insert dynamically cloned form into database together with other data using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i cloned some part of my checkout based on user input, i want to insert it with other data into database. this is my html checkout. `Class eventdetail` is the cloned part. it is shown at `id eventdisplay`. How can i insert this cloned part together with other parts using ajax into my database?

This is the jquery; i also want to check if all fields are filled but sending it to eventdetail.php.

```js
$("#book").click(function() {
        var data = {
           totalamount: $('#etamt').val(),
           venue: $('#cvenue').val(),
            //de: document.getElementById('des').innerHTML,
            oname:$('#coname').val(),
          // name: document.getElementById('ctitle').innerHTML,
             frdate: $('#cedate').val(),
            todate: $('#ctodate').val(),
            // byno: $('#buynumber').val(),
            // byemail: $('#buymail').val(),
            // byname: $('#buyname').val(),
             num: $('#etqty').val(),

        }
       $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: "eventdetail.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: $(data).serialize(),
            // $('.eventdetail').serialize(),
            success: function(rt) {

            }
        });
        console.log(data);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "col-12">
        
   <div class= "row">
      <div class= "col-6">
               <div class="form-group border-dark">
                   <label><strong>Info:     TEST</strong></label><br>
          <input id="cinfo"  value="TEST" type = "hidden"><br>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class= "col-6">
                <div class="form-group border-dark">
         <label><strong>Organized by:    Jochuks </strong></label><br>
                   <input id="coname" value="Jochuks" type = "hidden"><br>
                </div>
      </div>
   </div>
         <div class="form-group border-dark" id="datediv">
        <label><strong>Date and Time:</strong></label><br>
                <label><strong>From:    5th June 2019</strong></label>
                <input id="cedate"  value="5th June 2019" type = "hidden"><br>
       <label><strong>To:   23rd June 2019</strong></label>
              <input id="ctodate" value="23rd June 2019" type = "hidden"><br>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group border-dark" id="vendiv">
            <label><strong>Venue:    StackOver</strong></label><br>
            <input id="cvenue"  value="StackOver" type = "hidden"><br>
         </div>
   
 
   <div class = "eventdetail">
       <div class="card" style="padding-left:0px;">
          <div class="card-body">
            
           <label><b>Individual Details:</b></label>
   
           <div class="form-inline">
    
                   <div class="form-group border-dark">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="epname[]" placeholder="Enter individual's Full Name">
                         </div>
                <div class="form-group border-dark">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="epmail[]" placeholder="Enter individual's Email">
                         </div>
                <div class="form-group border-dark">
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="epnubmer[]" placeholder="Enter individual's Phone Number">
                         </div>
         </div>
        <section class="row">
                         <div align="center">
                             <a class="btn btn-outline-dark remove" >Remove Ticket</a>
                         </div>
                     </section>       
              </div>

          </div>
      </div>
  <div class="card" style="padding-left:0px;">
          <div class="card-body">
            
           <label><b>Individual Details:</b></label>
   
           <div class="form-inline">
    
                   <div class="form-group border-dark">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="epname[]" placeholder="Enter individual's Full Name">
                         </div>
                <div class="form-group border-dark">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="epmail[]" placeholder="Enter individual's Email">
                         </div>
                <div class="form-group border-dark">
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="epnubmer[]" placeholder="Enter individual's Phone Number">
                         </div>
         </div>
        <section class="row">
                         <div align="center">
                             <a class="btn btn-outline-dark remove" >Remove Ticket</a>
                         </div>
                     </section>       
              </div>

          </div>
 <div class="card" style="padding-left:0px;">
          <div class="card-body">
            
           <label><b>Individual Details:</b></label>
   
           <div class="form-inline">
    
                   <div class="form-group border-dark">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="epname[]" placeholder="Enter individual's Full Name">
                         </div>
                <div class="form-group border-dark">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="epmail[]" placeholder="Enter individual's Email">
                         </div>
                <div class="form-group border-dark">
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="epnubmer[]" placeholder="Enter individual's Phone Number">
                         </div>
         </div>
        <section class="row">
                         <div align="center">
                             <a class="btn btn-outline-dark remove" >Remove Ticket</a>
                         </div>
                     </section>       
              </div>

          </div>
 <div class="card" style="padding-left:0px;">
          <div class="card-body">
            
           <label><b>Individual Details:</b></label>
   
           <div class="form-inline">
    
                   <div class="form-group border-dark">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="epname[]" placeholder="Enter individual's Full Name">
                         </div>
                <div class="form-group border-dark">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="epmail[]" placeholder="Enter individual's Email">
                         </div>
                <div class="form-group border-dark">
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="epnubmer[]" placeholder="Enter individual's Phone Number">
                         </div>
         </div>
        <section class="row">
                         <div align="center">
                             <a class="btn btn-outline-dark remove" >Remove Ticket</a>
                         </div>
                     </section>       
              </div>

          </div>
      <div id = "eventdisplay">
   </div>
     <div class="card" style="padding-left:0px;">
       <div class="card-body">
   
           <div class="form-group border-dark pull-right">
                    <label><strong>   Total Amount:  20340</strong></label><br>
                     <input id="etamt"  value="20340" type = "hidden"><br>
                 </div>
           <div class="form-group border-dark pull-right">
                    <label><strong>Qty:   4</strong></label><br>
                    <input id="etqty"  value="4" type = "hidden">
        </div>
       </div>
  </div>
     
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block font-weight-bold mt-3 mb-3" id="book">BOOK</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block font-weight-bold mt-3 mb-3" id="back1">BACK</button>  
      
     </div>
```

Comment: A lot of the elements you are getting innerHTML from are not working. Try putting this in as a code snippet rather than just code blocks?

Comment: i displayed them in that checkout from database using innerHTML.  only these ones are input in that checkout     byno: $('#buynumber').val(),
                  byemail: $('#buymail').val(),
                  byname: $('#buyname').val(),

Comment: Those will keep throwing errors unless you have id's in the DOM to match your jQuery 'innerHTML' requests. You might want to rethink your strategy here

Comment: Thanks alot. i just created a snippet to show what i meant. The other values were displayed using innerhtml as showed there. the part with input is the part i cloned. Now i want to send everything in the checkout to database

Comment: It's still throwing errors because you are calling ID's of things that are not there. To succeed you will need to make sure every element you are calling is present in the DOM

Comment: Thanks alot for your effort to answer my question. i have edited it to remove all errors just for this platform because thats not how i did it in my work. Now my problem is to send input value of the 4 cloned part called "individual detail" with other values to eventdetail.php and how my eventdetail.php will insert it into database

Comment: Hey cool!  You might find this helpful! https://www.formget.com/php-data-object/

I wouldn't recommend doing this in raw PHP for a real project tho - you'll want to use a framework like Symfony or Laravel to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to solve your problem, but here's a snippet where I commented out the bits that weren't working.  Try putting a snippet like this into your question, with the things you need, and you'll be able to see what is and isn't working. You can also use https://codepen.io/  to build these things out and test more.

Consider using something other than jQuery, as it's pretty old these days!
[create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) is a nice starting point if you want to try react.

Writing validation libraries from scratch is a huge task, there are so many tools and plugins now you can use to avoid starting from the ground up:

- for jquery: https://jqueryvalidation.org/
- for react some insight: 
  https://www.telerik.com/blogs/up-and-running-with-react-form-validation

If you're just doing this for the joy of learning how to solve this problem with jQuery, that's cool! Feel free to comment on this answer and I'll update it to try and help you.  Here's the snippet example for your reference:

```js
$("#book").click(function() {
        var data = {
            totalamount: document.getElementById('etamt').innerHTML,
            venue: document.getElementById('cvenue').innerHTML,
            email: $('#cvemail').val(),
            // de: document.getElementById('des').innerHTML,
            // oname: document.getElementById('coname').innerHTML,
            name: document.getElementById('ctitle').innerHTML,
            // frdate: document.getElementById('cedate').innerHTML,
            // todate: document.getElementById('ctodate').innerHTML,
            // byno: $('#buynumber').val(),
            // byemail: $('#buymail').val(),
            // byname: $('#buyname').val(),
            // num: document.getElementById('etqty').innerHTML,
        }
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: "eventdetail.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: $(data).serialize(),
            // $('.eventdetail').serialize(),
            success: function(rt) {

            }
        });
        console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="userid">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="cvemail">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="form-group border-dark">
        <label><strong>Info:</strong></label><br>
        <label id="cinfo"></label><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="form-group border-dark">
        <label><strong>Organized by:</strong></label><br>
        <label id="coname"></label><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group border-dark" id="datediv">
    <label><strong>Date and Time:</strong></label><br>
    <label><strong>From:</strong></label>
    <label id="cedate"></label><br>
    <label><strong>To:</strong></label>
    <label id="ctodate"></label><br>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group border-dark" id="vendiv">
    <label><strong>Venue:</strong></label><br>
    <label id="cvenue"></label><br>
  </div>


  <div style="display:none" class="eventdetail">
    <div class="card" style="padding-left:0px;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <label class="pull-right" id="none"></label>
        <label id="con"></label><br>
        <label><b>Individual Details:</b></label>

        <div class="form-inline">

          <div class="form-group border-dark">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="epname[]" placeholder="Enter individual's Full Name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group border-dark">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="epmail[]" placeholder="Enter individual's Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group border-dark">
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="epnubmer[]" placeholder="Enter individual's Phone Number">
          </div>
        </div>
        <section class="row">
          <div align="center">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-dark remove">Remove Ticket</a>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="eventdisplay">
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="padding-left:0px;">
    <div class="card-body">

      <div class="form-group border-dark pull-right">
        <label><strong>   Total Amount:</strong></label><br>
        <label id="etamt"></label><br>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group border-dark pull-right">
        <label><strong>Qty:</strong></label><br>
        <label id="etqty"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block font-weight-bold mt-3 mb-3" id="book">BOOK</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block font-weight-bold mt-3 mb-3" id="back1">BACK</button>

</div>
```